# WLAN: Upload over specific router with specific laptop doesn't work

Tags: router, laptop, internet, wireless-router, upload

I have brand new acer Aspire V15 Nitro, instantly after opening it, I upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.

Connecting to home WiFi functioned very well. It is just recently (the first time I ever wanted upload) when I wanted to send an email and it took ages to send. And when sending emails with attachment it was way too long. I never waited until it was sent and cancelled it after 45 min of waiting (just so you have an image).
All this happens over home wifi. The laptop is right next to the wifi router.

Now: Every other wifi I connect to is working. School, work, public hotspots. Perfectly working, down- and upload.

And the other thing is: Every other device that is connected to my home wifi router is working with down- and upload perfectly (LAN or WiFi, it works). Only my laptop doesn't work over wifi, but it works over LAN of the same router.

Don't get me wrong, there is *still* a little bit upload left, so I can surf without noticing too much, but when I *really* want to upload, it fails. Even speedtests fail when it comes to upload, they just endlessly try to load.

- I tried deactivating firewall and antivirus, didn't work.
- I tried switching between 2,4 ghz and 5 ghz, didn't work.
- I switched from wifi to LAN cable, it worked (uploads then worked).
- I wanted to mirror a port on the router, but there is no option for
  that (so I could've looked what happens to the packets)
- I tried to upload over wifi on different times of the day (when there
  were less and more devices), but it didn't work either (so other devices are not the culprit)
- I even deactivated the only rule I had on my router, which was there to make sure I have a flawless NAT to my ps3 (just for gaming), it didn't work.
- I tried various wifi channels on my router, it didn't work.
- I restarted my router and my laptop a dozen times, it didn't work.
- I tried different browsers and applications for uploading to the internet on my laptop, it didn't work.

I am more than sure that something is wrong with my router, but the logs say everything is fine (no errors, no warnings). I just wanted to ask, if anybody has ever encountered a problem like that, and if anybody could help me with that.

Specs:
- Laptop: Acer Aspire V15 Nitro, Windows 10
- Router: Fritzbox 7390 (default from provider, due to that I don't have the possibility to update the routers firmware)

Answer (score 0):

I know you posted this a while ago, but I had the exact same issue - Acer Aspire v15 Nitro with Win 10 connecting to a Fritzbox.

After playing around for a while, I found simply downgrading the driver was what fixed it for me. I had driver version 4.0.something with a later date than the version I installed - 10.0.0.62, but it works so much better.

I'm now able to upload a 22 MB file in a matter of minutes, instead of it failing or timing out, and my sync folder says it will take 6 hours to upload everything in there instead of 3 years.