# WiFi upload doesn't work for the home router and laptop & android devices

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, android

All home devices are able to connect to the router, surf the web, chat in messengers. However, when one tries to send (upload) e.g. an image or another file bigger than few Kb, it stuns and shows as trying to send for hours.

To be clear enough: the issue isn't an upload speed, the upload doesn't merely work at all when you try to send a file in a messenger or upload an image to Facebook. A file gets stuck for hours with "Uploading..." status with no progress.

By "uploading" I mean a case when I try to send a file larger than roughly 100 Kb from the client to the web. The specific way in which I do it (as suggested: FTP, SCP, or via browser / messenger) doesn't seem to make much sense. I tried different ways, but the result is the same -- a file starts uploading (probably meaning that the uplink connection was established) but then gets stuck for a long time (a couple of hours for sure, didn't test more).

I say "file", because when I simply send a message in chat (Skype, Stride, HipChat and others) it delivers usually well (subjectively, 95% success rate).

Router: Asus RT-AC68U (Firmware Version: 3.0.0.4.374_379, HW version: A1)

Clients: MSI GE62 (Win 10), various Android 6-8 devices

Needless to say, all the clients work fine with Ethernet cable, over 3G/LTE data or in other WiFi networks.

The router supports both 2.4 and 5GHz networks, but neither of them works. I tried changing different settings, but they don't solve the issue:

- Changing channel bandwidth (20, 40 for 2.4 and 40, 80 for 5.0)
- Changing control channels
- Using only N mode
- Changing RTS Threshold in a range of 256-2347
- Enabling / disabling: WMM ASPD, TX Bursting

Dslreports test results: http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest/28634658

Simple speedtest seems to be OK, but "Upload" part feels a bit laggy at the beginning:
[image]

I already checked

- [WLAN: Upload over specific router with specific laptop doesn't work](https://superuser.com/questions/976447/wlan-upload-over-specific-router-with-specific-laptop-doesnt-work)
- [Windows 10 wifi upload issue](https://superuser.com/questions/980471/windows-10-wifi-upload-issue)
- [WiFi Upload crashing on One PC on One network](https://superuser.com/questions/1230252/wifi-upload-crashing-on-one-pc-on-one-network) and few others, but it's a bit different case

I would greatly appreciate any response or any wild guess that can help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it works for files over 1.5KiB but below 100KiB? If the cutoff were around 1.5KiB, I'd suspect a Path MTU Discovery problem or MSS Clamping problem and advise you to try setting your MTU down to 1400. A separate idea: Do any of your clients let you disable A-MPDU and A-MSDU (maybe in Windows' advanced driver properties for the Wi-Fi driver)? Try disabling both of those. Also, what is the hardware revision and firmware version of your RT-AC68U?

Comment: @Spiff file size numbers are more like "best guess". Thanks for suggesting MTU changes, I'll try to play with them (current MTU & MRU values are 1492). I'll also look for disabling both A-MPDU and A-MSDU on Windows / Android, but I'm a bit doubtful it has a place there. Added HW & FW versions to the question.

Comment: I see Asus now has newer firmware for RT-AC68U than what you have. The release notes mention fixes for NAT performance. Can you update to the latest firmware and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Thanks @Spiff, I'll give it a shot, hope that'd really be useful